# CMD succeeds in Informatica but does not get executed in actual

Tags: powershell, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a CMD task in a workflow.
When I run the workflow it says command executed successfully but nothing happens. The command is supposed to trigger another workflow.

Same CMD task is executing successfully in DEV environment i.e. executing another workflow.

Please find below for WF logs from both QA and DEV environments:
QA (Where log says it succeeds but does not trigger another WF):

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
INFO    8/8/2022 12:45:28 PM    NODE01_xxxxxQA1 4292    LM_36330    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: Execution started.
INFO    8/8/2022 12:45:28 PM    NODE01_xxxxxQA1 4292    LM_36620    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: running command [Command1], with command value [cmd /c "echo off |  powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "Script_Path\script.ps1"  2"].
INFO    8/8/2022 12:45:28 PM    NODE01_xxxxxQA1 2408    LM_36621    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: started command [Command1], with pid [3168] on node [NODE01_xxxxxQA1].
INFO    8/8/2022 12:45:30 PM    NODE01_xxxxxQA1 4256    LM_36624    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: execution of command [Command1] completed successfully
INFO    8/8/2022 12:45:30 PM    NODE01_xxxxxQA1 4256    LM_36318    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: Execution succeeded.
```

DEV (Where log says it succeeds and it triggers another WF):

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
INFO    8/8/2022 12:37:49 PM    NODE01_xxxxDEV1 5444    LM_36330    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: Execution started.
INFO    8/8/2022 12:37:49 PM    NODE01_xxxxDEV1 5444    LM_36620    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: running command [Command1], with command value [cmd /c "echo off |  powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "Script_Path\script.ps1"  2"].
INFO    8/8/2022 12:37:49 PM    NODE01_xxxxDEV1 5252    LM_36621    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: started command [Command1], with pid [3564] on node [NODE01_xxxxDEV1].
INFO    8/8/2022 12:40:06 PM    NODE01_xxxxDEV1 6052    LM_36624    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: execution of command [Command1] completed successfully
INFO    8/8/2022 12:40:06 PM    NODE01_xxxxDEV1 6052    LM_36318    Command task instance [Cmd_loop_run_wf_l]: Execution succeeded.
```

Comment: That sounds like a rights issue. Do you get the error if you run the process as an Administrator? It would be interesting to see what error(s) would show up if you had PerfMon running at the same time. Another option would be to log the $Error variable in between each of the calls...

Comment: **(CONT)**  Something similar to: `IF ($error.count -gt 0){
 Out-File -FilePath "C:\Some\Logfile.txt" -InputObject $error[0].ToString() -Append
    Out-File -FilePath "C:\Some\Logfile.txt" -InputObject $error[0].Exception.ToString() -Append
    Out-File -FilePath "C:\Some\Logfile.txt" -InputObject $error[0].ScriptStackTrace.ToString() -Append
        $error.clear()}` (I pulled that code from my function, so you may need to remove the `.tostring()` to get it to work correctly)

Comment: Are you sure qa has same rights? Its also possible, in QA, the script is taking a default route and throwing some exceptions and exiting normally. Which means script is successful but dint do its job. So like dbadon said, change uat script, add some debug points, re run using infa and see where its breaking down.